# php url error code

Tags: php, url, error-code

I define encoding in php file:

```
header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Now I write a link in my template file ( smarty )

```
<a href="http://www.test.cn/maternal_and_child/lists/中文测试">Link</a>
```

By the way, '中文测试' is chinese.But when I click the link, it return error like this:

```
The requested URL /maternal_and_child/app/webroot/lists/å‡†å¤‡æ€€å­•-ä¼˜ç”Ÿä¼˜è‚² was not found on this server.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry,I know the 'http://www.test.cn/' does exist, I want to know, why the character '中文测试' will change into '‡†å¤‡æ€€å­•-ä¼˜ç”Ÿä¼˜è‚²'

Answer (score 4):

`http://www.test.cn/maternal_and_child/lists/中文测试` is not a valid url. You should encode the url:

> http://www.test.cn/maternal_and_child/lists/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95

Answer (score 1):

Encode the URL with Smarty by using:

```
{* assuming the template variable $url holds your url *}
{$url|escape:'url'}
```

[Smarty `escape` docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.escape)

Comment: I try ( maternal_and_child/lists/?param=中文测试 ) then it work, but ( maternal_and_child/lists/中文测试 ) still don't work, And thank you, before it ,I use javascript to encode variable, now I know smarty have better one.